# rightnavbutton not changing (titanium alloy)

Tags: javascript, titanium-alloy

I am trying to change my right nav button:

```
function load_Profile() {
    if (editProfileFlag == 0) {

        $.win.rightNavButton = Ti.UI.createView({
            width : 'auto',
            height : 'auto'
        });

        var confirm = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title : 'Block',
            message : 'Are you sure? This cannot be undone. ',
            buttonNames : ['Yes', 'No'],
            cancel : 1
        });

        //add blocked button
        var blockButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title : 'Block',
            top : 0,
            zIndex: 10
        });

        //view mode
        if (args.view == 1) {

        } else {

            $.win.rightNavButton.add(blockButton);
        }

[...]
```

I use the same controller, for something else, so I need to override the existing rightnavbutton and replace it with a new one. Here is the xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win" >
        <RightNavButton>
            <Button id="btnRight" onClick="rightButtonClicked" />
        </RightNavButton>   

[...]
```

But the new button does not appear.

Any idea how to swap the right nav bar buttons?

Thanks.

Comment: why not just try to change the title of RightNavButton dynamically.

Comment: I need a way to hide the button until the text has changed, otherwise it is glitchy $.win.RightBavButton.setVisible=false; does not work